# Matrix generation in C++

Tags: c++, matrix

I have the following code:

```
for (int w=0; w<10; w++)
{
    //some lines of code
    unsigned long num = x.to_ulong(); 
    cout << "Decimal form is: " << num << endl;
}
```

Now what I want is, to make a matrix which will have these values of num, column wise. For example, `matrix[i][j]`, where `i` is from, let's say "0 to 15", and "j" is from "0 to 15" as well. I want them to put like, `matrix[0][0]`, then `matrix[0][1]`, `matrix[0][2]` and so on, something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<=15; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<=15; j++)
        matrix[i][j] = num //here is problem, value of "num" what shall i write instead of it?
}
```

Comment: Please clean this up and use syntax... Its really hard to read...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some pseudo code..

```
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned long> > matrix(15); // 15 rows
typedef std::vector<std::vector<unsigned long> >::iterator it_type;

it_type row = matrix.begin();

for (int w=0;w<10;w++)
{
  //some lines of code
  unsigned long num = x.to_ulong(); 
  cout <<"Decimal form is: " << num<< end;
  // if we've hit 15 items in the current row (i.e. 15 columns), then shift to the next row
  if (row->size() == 15)
    ++row;

  // add this to the next column in the current row
  row->push_back(num);
}
// resize the last row
row->resize(15); // this will ensure that there are 15 columns in the last row
```

NOTES: you'll have to do some bounds checking (for example if there are more numbers than 15 * 15, the incrementing the iterator `row` will lead to crap... etc.)

EDIT: to display, iterate through like a normal array, for example:

```
for(size_t i=0; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
{
  for(size_t j=0; j < matrix[i].size(); ++j)
    cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
  cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: are there any header files? because it is giving me 22 errors.

Comment: erm, yes... you need to include the header for `std::vector`, i.e. `<vector>`

Comment: and how shall I display this? cout what? Sorry, I am a newbie at C++

Comment: vector< vector < T > > is not the best way to create a matrix class. Far better to use just one vector internally. You can overload operator[] return T* or const T* depending on the overload.

Comment: @CashCow, I did write "pseudo" code at the top! ;) I don't have the time nor inclination to implement a full matrix class! ;)

Comment: @Nim, is it possibel to find maximum value and average value from matrix above?

Comment: Yes, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935630/find-maximum-minimum-average-of-a-matrix-in-c

Comment: i couldnot understand it well. CAn you please help in simplifying it a little?

Comment: If you cannot understand the code that is in the answers it means that your C++ really is *very* basic, and you need to fix that first! I suggest you pick up a beginner book on C++ and start from there. I can't tell you where to place this code, I don't know what you are doing, and the code in the answers cannot be simplified further - it's about as basic as it gets!

Comment: I am trying. Aright! I dont have much knowledge about vectors and matrices. long double matrix_min = std::min_element(matrix[0], matrix[0] + i*j); If I run it like row->push_back(res);
  
 }
 row->resize(15);
 for(size_t y=0; y < matrix.size(); ++y)
{
  for(size_t z=0; z < matrix[i].size(); ++z)
  {
 long double matrix_min = std::min_element(matrix[0], matrix[0] + y*z);
  }} it gives so many errors. Please kindly help, instead of being angry. thanks.

Comment: I am not being angry, I just don't have the time to write your code, you have been given enough information in all the answers, and you have to take some initiative to understand those answers. You cannot expect people to do everything for you.

Comment: I have tried following as well, but still its giving 9 errors:   for ( it_type=matrix.begin() ; it_type < matrix.end(); it_type++ )
  {  cout << ' ' << min_element(it_type->begin(), it_type->end());}

Comment: it's not about errors, you just have not grasped the language, you really need to learn it first, you cannot rush headlong into something like this without understanding the language, let me put it more basically, you are apparently trying to run a marathon before you can even crawl! *learn the language first!*

Comment: arrite. Thanks! but i was wondering, if still there is anyway you could help me in finding max and min values, please! I will take your advice and will learn from the basics..

Comment: No point, any code that is provided will need further explanations, you've been given the code for this already, and you cannot understand it, you need to fix that problem first!

Comment: Okay. Any link, or material you can provide to understand vector, iterator etc?

Comment: this is a reference for vector: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/, tells you all the methods available and so forth. The following is a reference for all the algorithms, the answers to your other question uses these algorithms: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/

Answer (score 0):

Standard "use Boost" answer:

If you just need a two-dimensional array, check out [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html).

If you need to do linear algebra, check out [Boost.uBlas](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm).