# Find maximum, minimum, average of a matrix in C++

Tags: c++, matrix

How do I find the maximum, minimum and average values in a given matrix (`matrix[i][j]`) in C++. The type is unsigned long double.

Comment: **unsigned** long double?  Your platform has unsigned floating point types?

Comment: This is the 3rd question you've asked on this topic in the last couple hours.  Are these homework problems by chance?

Comment: @stephen: hahaha :) I did not notice !

Answer (score 9):

There's nothing clever to be done here (pseudocode only, since this smells like HW):

```
for each entry in the matrix:
    add the entry to a running sum
    compare the entry to a running min
        if it's smaller, it's the new running min
    compare the entry to a running max
        if it's larger, it's the new running max
average is the sum divided by the number of entries
```

You can micro-optimize that loop to make it more or less efficient, but there's nothing you can do *algorithmically* to be more clever.  You need to look at all `i*j` entries no matter what.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this:

**Maximum**:

```
int maximum = 0;
for(int x=0; x<width; ++x)
  for(int y=0; y<height; ++y)
    maximum = std::max(matrix[x][y], maximum);
```

**Minimum**:

```
int minimum = 0;
for(int x=0; x<width; ++x)
  for(int y=0; y<height; ++y)
    minimum = std::min(matrix[x][y], minimum);
```

**Avarage**:

```
int avarage = 0;
for(int x=0; x<width; ++x)
  for(int y=0; y<height; ++y)
    avarge += matrix[x][y];
avarge /= width*height;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `matrix` is an actual C++ two-dimensional array could you use standard algorithms.

Untested code:

```
long double mean = std::accumulate(matrix[0], matrix[0] + i*j, 0.0) / (i*j);
long double matrix_min = std::min_element(matrix[0], matrix[0] + i*j);
long double matrix_max = std::max_element(matrix[0], matrix[0] + i*j);
```

Do note that this does extra passes over the matrix at the benefit of being clear what it's doing.

If it's another container type like a `vector` of `vector`s then you'd have to run the algorithms on each row and take the max of each row.

Comment: for(size_t i=0; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
{
  for(size_t j=0; j < matrix[i].size(); ++j)
  {
    cout << matrix[i][j] <<" ";
  } I have this type of code. It includes vector. Now what shall I do?

Comment: you iterate 3 times over the matrix to do this though. One pass will do

Comment: can you please elaborate it a little. I am new at C++.

Comment: @CashCow Excuse my ignorance, but how would you calculate all three terms with one pass?

Comment: As you run through the elements you keep sum, max and min and at the end you divide sum by the number of elements to get the mean. You can also calculate the sum of squares to get variance if you really want. Just run through each element and collect stats on the way with an object that pushes it in, You can use for_each for that purpose as that takes a predicate. Or a loop. What is matrix[0]?

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all the values, recording current max, min, and cumulative sum.  Then divide the cumulative sum by the number of elements to get the mean.