# maximum and minimum value?

Tags: c++

I have made a matrix using vector and iterator, how can I find maximum and minimum value from it. It is something like:

```
vector<int> > matrixes(10);
typedef std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator it;

it rows = matrixes.begin();
 if (rows->size() == 10)
++rows;
rows->push_back(res);

}

for(size_t q=0; q < matrixes.size(); ++q)
{
    for(size_t r=0; q < matrixes[q].size(); ++r)
    cout << matrixes[q][r] << " ";
   cout << endl;
}
```

I want to find maximum and minimum value through it, how is it possible?

Comment: Didn't we see this question yesterday? Find it and close as dup...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find maximum, minimum, average of a matrix in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935630/find-maximum-minimum-average-of-a-matrix-in-c)

Comment: oh this resembles my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add two variables to hold the maximum and minimum value.
Update the portion where you display it.

```
vector<int> > matrixes(10);
typedef std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator it;

it rows = matrixes.begin();

int maxVal,minVal;

if ( matrixes.size() > 0 && matrixes[0].size() > 0 )
 maxVal = minVal =  matrixes[0][0];

for(size_t q=0; q < matrixes.size(); ++q)
{
    for(size_t r=0; q < matrixes[q].size(); ++r)
    {        
     cout << matrixes[q][r] << " ";
     cout << endl;
     // update min, max here
     maxVal= maxVal<matrixes[q][r]?matrixes[q][r]:maxVal;
     minVal= minVal>matrixes[q][r]?matrixes[q][r]:minVal;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Its displayed here:cout << matrixes[q][r] << " ";

Comment: thank you very much. Is it also possible to find standard deviation of values of this matrix?

Comment: Yes you can get that. Just find average, and loop ever each element to get the difference of square, and find the root of sum.

Answer (score 4):

Use [std::max_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/) and [std::min_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/) in the STL.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little on how to use these. As I am new in C++

Comment: use them with iterator, vectors, matrices?

Comment: Using these two functions is little bit complex for beginners (I am assuming ellen8998 is new to C++).

Comment: @Gunner: Not really. You pass `begin()` and `end()` and get a result, not much simpler than that. (Well, a better designed standard library could make it *even* simpler.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have an std::vector, you can do

```
std::vector<int> my_vector;
//Populate vector
int max = std::max_element( my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end() );
```

See [the reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/).

Answer (score 0):

```
std::sort( matrixes.begin(), matrixes.end() );
```

First element in vector will be the least and the last element will be greatest.

Comment: sort is O(N.LogN) while a for loop or std::max_element and std::min_element are O(n)